# How to persist a model when doing Create / Edit in MVC3 before saving it to the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model

basically I am talking about the thing what we had in ASP.NET, called ViewState.
Here is the example, to keep it simple, I have a model Employee:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

My company created records for employees with their EmployeeId, Name and Company.
The employee needs to enter (update) only his Phone number and Address.
When I present a form in Edit / or Create mode for employee to enter this information, EmployeeID, Name and Company outputted just as text, while Phone and Address are editable fields (Html.EditorFor), which allows to keep values entered in the Model object.

When this form is HTTP posted back, lets say, validation fails, and the form is presented to the user again to correct his input (View(model)).

However the values for EmployeeID, Name and Company are lost, since they were not defined as Html.EditorFor, like Phone and Address, and therefore are not preserved, when the submitted model is being passed again into the View.

How do I preserve (persist) in the Model those properties (that are not editable)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use Html.HiddenFor and store the values on the page. You could also use the mvc futures project and Html.Serialize it, but then you are mimicking viewstate when it's not necessary.

Comment: That was my first choice to use Html.HiddenFor.
I wasn't sure if this is the "correct" MVC approach.
So, basically if I have a model with 20 fields, where 19 fields are used for display only, and only 1 field is editable, I would have to place 19 Html.HiddenFor elements?

Comment: Yes, although in that case storing that many fields on the client side you may as well cache them or store the object in tempdate and retrieve on postback since the page is being used as nothing more than a storage mechanism then. TempData does use the session object behind the scenes, so beware of the performance concerns with that as well for overlapping requests for the current user.